# Error FPWSE1060W to send push notification in ibm mobilefirst 7.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I am working on native-hybrid App using MobileFirst 7.0. The app use notifications push managed by MobileFirst. Notifications are sent using an MobileFirst adapter. Occasionally we are receiving the following error when sending notifications push:

> **com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.gcm.TimeoutQueue W FPWSE1060W: GCM: 1 notifications deleted from the queue GCM-sender-AIzaSyAE because the waiting time is more than 50,000 sec.**

Any idea why this error happens?

Answer (score 0):

This error is a known problem that was recently fixed: PI67242 PUSH NOTIFICATION WONT SENT IN ANDROID DEVICES GCM WHEN MAXQUEUE LENGTH IS HIT

The fix for MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0 is available starting the build number dated 20160830-0817.

Please head over to IBM Fix Central and download the latest available iFix for MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0, which includes this fix and see if your issue is resolved.